# How to spool a number in oracle in correct format

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, spool

I am trying to spool the records by executing script in SqlDeveloper, everything is working fine except printing the record of columns which are NUMBER(38,0) data type.

All numbers record are printing in below format:

**`1.5E+18`**

I tried many combinations by using set but nothing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/TO_CHAR-number.htm#SQLRF06130); for example:

```
SQL> select to_char(n, '999999999999999999999') from numbers;

TO_CHAR(N,'99999999999
----------------------
   1500000000000000000
```

This way you can decide the exact format you want to use; for example:

```
SQL> select to_char(n, 'FM999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999') from numbers;

TO_CHAR(N,'FM999G999G999G999G999
--------------------------------
1.500.000.000.000.000.000
```

If you don't need a full control on the format, and/or you don't want to chenge your code, you can follow the suggestion by Nicholas Krasnov :

```
SQL> set numwidth 50
SQL> select n from numbers;

                                                 N
--------------------------------------------------
                               1500000000000000000
```

Comment: or `set numwidth 50` (50 is maximum allowable value). So you do not have to rewrite the script.

Comment: Actually, in my script, I have 164 select statements and most of the statements having number data type column so, in this condition, it's difficult for me to change in all places.